# CakePHP - where is the best place to put logic for a specific layout?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, session, cakephp

I am using a layout which has three lists which are created from a database query. I would propose to put this data in the session so the app doesn't have to query the database on every page load.

The admin section of the app will not need this data as it uses a different layout. In cakePHP where is the best place to put the logic that sets this session data?

Is the best approach to create another controller that extends the AppController and looks after setting this session data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create elements for these 3 lists. The best way to do this is using [requestAction and elements](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gwoo/2007/04/12/creating-reusable-elements-with-requestaction). Using elements also allows you to cache the output, which is always a good idea.

Comment: What I need is layout specific data, i.e. I do not want this data being generated for my admin layout.

Comment: It is not going to be generated in your admin layout, unless you use `$this->element` and explicit use any of these 3 elements. CakePHP's "elements" are like ruby on rails' "partials". They are reusable HTML codes where you can place in any layout... It is not going to be in beforeRender() for every request. It is CALLED BY THE LAYOUT and USED ONLY IN LAYOUTS.

Answer (score 1):

specify it in beforeRender() in AppController. If you have beforeRender() in any controller, remember to call parent::beforeRender()

Comment: But I do not need this data for my admin section which will inherit from AppController. Basically I only want the data for my default.ctp template...

Comment: you can always check on the current layout in this method and react accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still fairly new to CakePHP, so this may not be the best way to do this, but I would have a model using a custom behaviour to checks if session data has been loaded and load the data from the session or database dependant on whether its been loaded already. So I think the code  could be written as a behaviour and the model would then be used wherever necessary. Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I don't like to use sessions in my models. If you don't want to query the database, just use cache. That's what it is for =)

Comment: Models should not use sessions.